# What are error's regarding Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I have tried to **scrape** a table with `BeautifulSoup` and out of my 4 attempts first 3 are not working I don't know why!

In fourth approach I have tried using `pandas` but results are not specific anymore.

```py
import requests
import bs4

res = requests.get(
    "https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/marketstats/industry-classification/bse/aerospace-defence.html")

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

# 1st try by copy selector from inspect element
table = soup.find_all(
    '#mc_content > section > section > div.clearfix.stat_container > div.columnst.FR.wbg.brdwht > div > div.bsr_table.hist_tbl_hm.PR.Ohidden')
print(table)
```

```py
# 2nd try by specifically writing class by attribute method
table = soup.find_all(
    'div', attrs={'class': 'bsr_table.hist_tbl_hm.PR.Ohidden'})
print(table)
```

```py
# 3rd conventional style
table = soup.find('table')
table_rows = table.find('tr')
for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [i.text() for i in td]
        print(td)
```

```py
import pandas as pd

# 4th by pandas

dfs = pd.read_html(
    'https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/marketstats/industry-classification/bse/aerospace-defence.html')
for df in dfs:
        print(df)
```

Output I got:

```
0   Hindustan Aeron  Add to  Watchlist | Portfolio...  ...      627.53
1                                               5-Day  ...         NaN
2                                              10-Day  ...         NaN
3                                              30-Day  ...         NaN
4                                               3-Day  ...         NaN
5                                               5-Day  ...         NaN
6                                               8-Day  ...         NaN
7   TAAL Enterprise  Add to  Watchlist | Portfolio...  ...      135.34
8                                               5-Day  ...         NaN
9                                              10-Day  ...         NaN
10                                             30-Day  ...         NaN
11                                              3-Day  ...         NaN
12                                              5-Day  ...         NaN
13                                              8-Day  ...         NaN
14  Taneja Aerospac  Add to  Watchlist | Portfolio...  ...       21.76
15                                              5-Day  ...         NaN
16                                             10-Day  ...         NaN
17                                             30-Day  ...         NaN
18                                              3-Day  ...         NaN
19                                              5-Day  ...         NaN
20                                              8-Day  ...         NaN
```

**But Output I want:**

```
is a data frame having columns 1)Open 2) High 3) Low 4) Price 5)Current Price 6) Percent change 7) Sector:- aerospace defence.
```

Thanks for answering doubt and contributing to it.

Comment: Welcome to `Stack Overflow` Community, I've edit much mistakes on your post. kindly pay attention for [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your future questions. also please edit your question and include the expected output as the current one is not `understandable`

Comment: I want a ouptu something like 
     Stock Open High Low Current Price %change for an hour 
    Hindustan Aeron 630  641  629 634  -1.21% 

to know it specifically u can opne link its okk if u dont solve perecnt change becuase thats old values and new values

Comment: you have to include it in your question, anyway I've included it for you. but for your future posts, kindly click on edit under your question and include as much as you can from information to make it easier for both of us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the page is loaded via `JavaScript` so you couldn't use `requests` module to parse a `JS` which is `rendered` dynamically once the page loads.

You can use `selenium` for such task. otherwise you could do it with `HTMLSession` from `requests_html` module which render the `JavaScript` on the fly.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import pandas as pd

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/marketstats/industry-classification/bse/aerospace-defence.html")


df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]

print(df)
df.to_csv("result.csv", index=False)

driver.quit()
```

output: [VIEW-ONLINE](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/98b5d3d3e61fc9e5859a92ffb91dde43/result.csv)

```
                                        Company Name  ...  5 Day Performance -18.45 (-2.7%)  03-Mar-20  6...  5 Day Performance  Volume  Lower Circuit  Upper Circuit  VWAP  SMA Deliver -0.3 (-0.19%)  03-Mar-20  15...ables  P/E  P/B                                                             0.55 (2.26%)  03-Mar-20  24.4...
0  Hindustan Aeron  Add to  Watchlist | Portfolio...  ...  02-Mar-20  666.10 -18.45 (-2.7%)  03-Mar-20  6...
1  TAAL Enterprise  Add to  Watchlist | Portfolio...  ...  02-Mar-20  160.00 -0.3 (-0.19%)  03-Mar-20  15...
2  Taneja Aerospac  Add to  Watchlist | Portfolio...  ...  02-Mar-20  24.90 
0.55 (2.26%)  03-Mar-20  24.4...

[3 rows x 9 columns]
```

[image]

> Note: for your knowledge, Pay attention that `pd.read_html` is actually returning a list. so you don't need to loop over it. you can just index it using `df[0]` for example.

Comment: Thank You So much ahmed american
But can you answer why above three didint gave answers

Comment: @SMEETKOTHARI you have to read the description which I've included before the code !

Comment: @SMEETKOTHARI To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in ,that's in case if it's resolved your issue.